# Redirect after login not working

Tags: django, django-registration

I've been searching around but can't figure out why the redirection after login is not working as expected.

I successfully login at `http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/`. After that I'm always redirected to `http://localhost:8000` no matter if I use settings.py variable `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` or if I leave it completely out.

```
# urls.py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),
    url(r'^$', 'myapp.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^home/$', 'myapp.views.apphome', name='apphome'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),    
    (r'^admin/', include("massadmin.urls")),
)
```

I don't know where I should start looking for a problem. Any ideas? Is there some settings I'm missing here? Any other files I should include to help debug the problem?

Comment: What is your form action?

Comment: Ah, that was the problem! By default the `login.html` template contains this line `<form method="post" action="?next={{ next|default:"/" }}">`. After removing the default part I can redirect wherever I want. If you want to provide an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @möter I will if mwmeyer doesn't write the answer. I'll give him some time though because the credit belongs to him. He provided the right hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your form action! (glad I could help :) )

Comment: By default the `login.html` template contains this line `<form method="post" action="?next={{ next|default:"/" }}">`. After removing the default part I can redirect wherever I want. Thanks for the hint!